# Android Safe Start Mode for Application

Tags: android, safe-mode

Is it possible to have a safe start mode for your Android Application. In the sense that the application will not start the main activity (which is intense) but will open another activity which will have tools to fix some of these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create flag in shared preferences to store whether your app was closed properly or check something else you need. Then add one part before (activity or what you need) where you check this and decide about the mode you are getting in.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: my plan was to record the last 3 or 5 app open times in preferences and if the app was opened 3 or 5 times in a minute then forward to safe activity